# how can I use jpcap library in my project?

Tags: java, netbeans, network-programming, jpcap

I am using Netbeans 7, and I have 32 bit JDK version 1.7.0.40. I want to use jpcap library to analyze incoming packets.

I do following to be able to use jpcap.

```
I added "jpcap.jar" into my project's library.
I copied "jpcap.dll" into my JRE/bin
I copied "jpcap.jar" into my JDK/jre/lib/ext
I copied "jpcap.jar" into my JRE/lib/ext
```

However, I  get the exception below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jpcap.JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList()[Ljpcap/NetworkInterface;
at jpcap.JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList(Native Method)
at src.JpcapAnalyzer.<init>(JpcapAnalyzer.java:19)
at src.Main.main(Main.java:31)
```

Java Result: 1

I appreciate for any recommendations.

***Edit :*** 
After 2 weeks posting this question, I received no answers. Then I want to share my experience with the community.

I tried another library,**jnetpcap**, which can be downloaded at https://sourceforge.net/projects/jnetpcap/. I easily implemented it. You can use this library both in 32 bit and 64 bit OS and JDK.